# Move files to a folder named by part of their filename

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, script, gopro

I have files from a GoPro Fusion camera
that represent images and movies. 
The filenames look like

```
GP                                          (for “GoPro”)
(two more letters of no particular significance)
(a series of digits; maybe four or six digits)
.                                           (a period)
(an extension)
```

Some of the extensions are common ones,
like `JPG`, `MP4`, and `WAV`; others are uncommon. 
Some example filenames are `GPFR0000.jpg`, `GPBK0000.jpg`, `GPFR0000.gpr`, `GPFR1153.MP4`, `GPFR1153.THM` and `GPBK142857.WAV`. 
But the extensions aren’t relevant to this question.

For each image and movie there is a set of files
whose names have the same series of digits
right before the extension. 
So, for example, `GPFR1153.LRV` and `GPBK1153.MP4`
belong to the same set.

I want all the files from each set to be grouped in a directory
whose name is `GP` followed by the series of digits. 
For example, if I have

```
GPFR0000.jpg
GPBK0000.jpg
GPFR0000.gpr
GPFR0000.gpr
GPFR1153.LRV
GPFR1153.MP4
GPFR1153.THM
GPBK1153.WAV
GPBK1153.MP4
GPQZ142857.FOO
```

all in one directory, the outcome should be

```
GP0000\GPFR0000.jpg
GP0000\...
GP1153\GPFR1153.LRV
GP1153\GPFR1153.MP4
GP1153\...
GP142857\GPQZ142857.FOO
```

Would this be possible with a script (for Windows 10)? 
I found this (PowerShell) script by [mousio](https://serverfault.com/users/79348/mousio) at
[Recursively move thousands of files into subfolders windows](https://serverfault.com/q/471828/201794#471900),
but it addresses a slightly different problem,
and I’d like help adapting it to my requirements
(I’m an artist, not a programmer).

```
# if run from "P:\Gopro\2018", we can get the image list
$images = dir *.jpg

# process images one by one
foreach ($image in $images)
{
    # suppose $image now holds the file object for "c:\images\GPBK1153.*"

    # get its file name without the extension, keeping just "GPBK1153"
    $filenamewithoutextension = $image.basename

    # group by 1 from the end, resulting in "1153"
    $destinationfolderpath = 
        $filenamewithoutextension -replace '(....)$','\$1'

    # silently make the directory structure for "1153 GPBK1153"
    md $destinationfolderpath >$null

    # move the image from "c:\images\1234567890.jpg" to the new folder "c:\images\1\234\567\890\"
    move-item $image -Destination $destinationfolderpath

    # the image is now available at "P:\Gopro\2018\1153\GPBK1153.*"
}
```

Comment: (1) Your script shows filenames that look like Windows filenames.  Are you running Windows?  Please [edit] you question to say so, specifying version, in both the question body and the tags.  (2) You say your files follow a pattern, and you show a few examples, but you don’t explain it.  You show filenames that are four letters, four digits, a period, and a three letter extension.  Is the pattern that all files with the same four digits are related?  So `BLUE1742.FOO` and `IRON1742.BAR` go together?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Please explain the result that you want.  (Your question title hints at your goals, but you give no details.)  (4) Where did you get that script?  If somebody else wrote it, you must identify the source.  (5) Where’s the rest of the script?  You show a `{` but no `}`, so you’re missing part.  (6) What is your question?  (7) Why aren’t you asking the author of the script for help?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: (1) Yes Win 10
(2) Yes 4 digits in rare cases more (6)
(3) a folderstructure containing each image set wit named folder by digits
(4),(5) source was added Sorry
(6) could you help me doing this script
(7) i don't know why. I just thought this to be the right way since there is also many other people using this camere and having to solve having this issue.

i'm sorry i just googled this and tried to find answers...
please do not get offended. 
I can of course delete this if this is not the appropirate

Comment: I wasn’t offended; I’m sorry if I gave you that impression.  The problem is that we can’t read your mind, and we can’t answer your question if we don’t understand what you want.  Also, copying something written by somebody else without identifying the original author, even within the [SE] family, is considered plagiarism and is strictly forbidden. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  While I’m not offended, I am frustrated, because I asked you what result you wanted, and you gave me two different answers.  Your comment says that you want files moved into a directory (folder) whose name is the digits from the filename, and the example comments that you put into the script say that you want files ```GPBK1153.*``` moved into directory `1153`.  But, in your examples at the beginning of the question, you say that the directory name should be `GP1152`.  (And the fact that you switched from `1152` to `1153` confused me for a moment.) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I assumed that you want the directory name to be ```GP``` followed by the digits; let me know if that’s wrong.  **Update:** I have made a large edit to your question. Again, let me know if I got anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my (possibly flawed) understanding of what you want,
you can do it with the following PowerShell script. 
Note that this is derived from a work by [mousio](https://serverfault.com/users/79348/mousio), posted at
[Recursively move thousands of files into subfolders windows](https://serverfault.com/q/471828/201794#471900).

```
# If run from "P:\Gopro\2018", we can get the file list.
$images = dir GP*

# Process files one by one.
foreach ($image in $images)
{
    # Suppose $image now holds the file object for "P:\Gopro\2018\GPBK1153.FOO"

    # Get its file name without the extension, keeping just "GPBK1153".
    $filenamewithoutextension = $image.basename

    # Grab the first two characters (which we expect to be "GP"),
    # skip the next two characters (which we expect to be letters; e.g., "BK"),
    # then grab all the characters after that (which we expect to be digits; e.g., "1153")
    # and put them together, resulting in "GP1153".
    $destinationfolderpath = 
        $filenamewithoutextension -replace '(..)..(.*)','$1$2'

    # Silently make the directory structure for "GP1153".
    md $destinationfolderpath > $null 2>&1

    # Move the file from "P:\Gopro\2018\GPBK1153.FOO" to the new folder "P:\Gopro\2018\GP1153"
    move-item $image -Destination $destinationfolderpath

    # The file is now available at "P:\Gopro\2018\GP1153\GPBK1153.FOO".
}
```